# Word not opening specific files for a specific user

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have the problem that for specific files word is staying almost forever in starting mode (aka more than 10 minutes). Then when the starting mode is over with word is open but without a file opened inside of it.

These files are network files, but the same problem occurs when I put them locally.

Now I've read about template problems in the past (thus that word takes forever to open files where the templates are not existing any longer because the server they are on disappeared, ....) and considered that BUT the problem is that other users who have the same configurations for network drives and the same word versions don't encounter this problem at all with these files, so I take it that it is not a template problem.

My question is thus: What can cause such a problem to occur?